# javascript regex get specific substring

Tags: javascript, regex

How could I get the specific substring between `'Y___(string i want to get)___N'`？
For example：

```
"Y___INT_GET_ERROR_CONFIGS___N" 
"INT_GET_ERROR_CONFIGS"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get everything inside by `Y___(.*?)___N`, you can use `matchAll` to get all instance that matches this case, and you can loop through and get the group value.

```js
const str = `Y___INT_GET_ERROR_CONFIGS___N
INT_GET_ERROR_CONFIGS Y___INT_GET_ERROR_SOMETHING___N`

const result = str.matchAll(/Y___(.*?)___N/g);

for (match of result) {
  console.log(match[1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the first occurrence you wish you match, then:

```js
'Y___(string you want to get)___N'.match(/(?<=Y___).+(?=___N)/)

Result:
"(string you want to get)"
```

If you want all such occurrences to be returned, then use the `g` flag:

```js
`Y___(string you want to get)___N
         .
         .
         .
 Y___(second string you want)___N`.match(/(?<=Y___).+(?=___N)/g)

Result:
["(string you want to get)", "(second string you want)"]
```

##### Explanation:

- **`(?<=Y___)`**: A ***positive lookbehind*** stipulates that matches will be preceded by the contents of the lookbehind, namely `"Y___"`.  The contents of the lookbehind does not form part of the match result, and also does not consume characters during matching.
- **`.+`**: Matches at least one instance of any character, but will match as many as possible.
- **`(?=___N)`**: A ***positive lookahead*** stipulates that matches will be proceeded by the contents of the lookahead, namely `"___N"`.  The contents of the lookahead does not form part of the match result, nor does it consume characters during matching.